# Закрыть ЛЮБУЮ вкладку  javascript

Tags: javascript

Необходимо закрыть любую вкладку с помощью javascript. Подойдет вариант даже правки конфига браузера, лишь бы сработал window.close() вкладки моего сайта открытого не только через window.open()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может, с плагином/примочкой, установленной в браузере, можно такие вольности осуществить. «Решения» под каждый браузер понадобятся индивидуальные.

Например, Extensions под Chrome могут себе позволить [закрыть любой таб](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-remove).

Comment: +1 или firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/XPCOM/Language_Bindings

Answer (score 2):

Никкак. Чтобы закрыть вкладку, нужно иметь объект window, ссылающийся на неё. Такой объект вы можете получить только открыв новую вкладку из своего скрипта. Требования безопасности не позволяют программе на Javascript оперировать чем-либо, выходящим за рамки "песочницы", в которой она запускается (в данном случае это вкладка, на которой запущен скрипт). Правки конфига тут не помогут. Разве что править исходники какого-нибудь открытого движка (вроде WebKit). Но не думаю, что перекомпиляция движка в вашем случае приемлимый вариант.

Comment: Браузер перекомпилировать... о_О А расширения по-твоему для чего нужны?

Answer (score 0):

Может не совсем в тему, но для FF пойдет:
window.location.replace('about:blank');

в хроме уже не работает